# how to get the contact number from contacts in android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my application i want to get the contact number from contacts and print it on the edit text. I wrote code from google. but it is not working.

java:

```
 private void browseContacts() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
    pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only
    // contacts w/ phone
    // numbers
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request it is that we're responding to
    Log.v("TAG_CONTACTNAME",""+POSTPAID_SERVICETYPEID);
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

                int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {

                    String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);
                    Log.v("TAG_CONTACTNAME",""+phoneNumber);
                     } while (cursor.moveToNext()); }
                    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {

                        if (cursor != null) { cursor.close();
                        } }

        }


    }

}
```

please help me

Comment: i wrote permission in manifest file too

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no fahim...i am not getting number from  contact screen. no error

Answer (score 2):

Just call this method(GetAllContacts)

```
 public void GetAllContacts(){
     ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

     if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                       new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                      String phone = pCur.getString(
                             pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                      contactsNumber.add(phone);
                      Log.d("Number is", phone);
                }
                pCur.close();    
            }
        }
   }
}
```

And add this in menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in onActivityResult

```
Cursor cursor = null; 
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); 
            int contactIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone._ID);
            int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            int photoIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.PHOTO_ID);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do { 
                String idContact = cursor.getString(contactIdIdx); String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx); 
                String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);
                //... 
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } finally {

            if (cursor != null) { 
                cursor.close();
            } 
        }
```

and also this in your manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: @FAHIM....onActivityresult is not calling....i will edt my code //please see once

Comment: Accept the answer if u are satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Go on this link see all code step by step getting all contacts list whatever you need to it like as numbers, email, notes etc...

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/06/13/get-all-details-from-contacts-in-android/

This method put in your onCreate method,

```
  public void readContacts(){
     ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

     if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                // get the phone number
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                       new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                      String phone = pCur.getString(
                             pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                      System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                }
                pCur.close();


                // get email and type

               Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // This would allow you get several email addresses
                        // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                    String email = emailCur.getString(
                                  emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                                  emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                  System.out.println("Email " + email + " Email Type : " + emailType);
                }
                emailCur.close();

                // Get note.......
                String noteWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                String[] noteWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                        Cursor noteCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, noteWhere, noteWhereParams, null);
                if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String note = noteCur.getString(noteCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));
                  System.out.println("Note " + note);
                }
                noteCur.close();

                //Get Postal Address....

                String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, null, null, null);
                while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String poBox = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
                    String street = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
                    String city = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
                    String state = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
                    String postalCode = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
                    String country = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
                    String type = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));

                    // Do something with these....

                }
                addrCur.close();

                // Get Instant Messenger.........
                String imWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                String[] imWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                Cursor imCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, imWhere, imWhereParams, null);
                if (imCur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String imName = imCur.getString(
                             imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
                    String imType;
                    imType = imCur.getString(
                             imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));
                }
                imCur.close();

                // Get Organizations.........

                String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
                if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
                    String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
                }
                orgCur.close();
            }
        }
   }
}
```

I hope solution you have.

Last one very important **permission** add in Manifest xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: Add code to the answer. If the link expires, the answer becomes invalid

Comment: OK, this code try it out i hope solution you will get

Comment: This code of method put in your java file and run it, I hope all contact got and solution you have.